# Tablesorter - Sort date inside input field

Tags: jquery, date, tablesorter

Trying to sort columns by dates.  These columns are in MM/DD/YY format, so I have to change it to 20YY-MM-DD.  From the docs I've read, this should do it, but it is not.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
     $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id:  "inputdate",
        is: function() {
                return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table) {
          // reformat mm/dd/yy to mm/dd/20yy
          var d = (s == "") ? "01/01/00" : $.trim($('input', cell).val());
          if(d == "") { // if blank, set a default
            d = "01/01/00";
          }  
      return Date.parse( '20' + d.substr(6,2) + '-' + d.substr(0,2) + '-' + d.substr(3,2) );    
        },
        type: "numeric"
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I recommend adding the primary language tag — is it [tag:javascript]?  And maybe the primary JavaScript package tag too — is it [tag:jquery]?

Comment: I realize that "format: function(s, table)" should be format: function(s, table, cell).  Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Edit your question to fix the typo — and add the tags too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `format` function is missing the `cell` parameter:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id:  "inputdate",
  is: function() {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table, cell) {
    // reformat mm/dd/yy to mm/dd/20yy
    var d = (s == "") ? "01/01/00" : $.trim($('input', cell).val());
    if(d == "") { // if blank, set a default
      d = "01/01/00";
    }  
    return Date.parse( '20' + d.substr(6,2) + '-' + d.substr(0,2) + '-' + d.substr(3,2) );    
  },
  type: "numeric"
});
```

Also make sure to point to this parser in the `headers` option:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  headers: {
    // zero-based column index
    0 : { sorter: 'inputdate' }
  }
});
```

The parser wasn't tested to make sure it works. Please provide some HTML or set up a JSFiddle if it still doesn't work.